# Rails: array.join with html in separator is escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-escape

I have an array of Strings containing unsave content (user input).

I want to join these Strings in my template, separated by `<br />`.

I tried:

```
somearray.join("<br />")
```

But this will also escape the sparator.

Is there a workaround, keeping in mind that the content of the array absolutely must be escaped?

Comment: Did you try somearray.join("<br />".html_safe) ?

Comment: Yes, it is still being escaped.

Comment: Yes should be as parts of the string are not safe. Then the whole string is considered as unsafe.

Comment: Found the following workaround: `simple_format(somearray.join("\r\n"))`, but I think there must be a better solution

Comment: Another workaround: `h(somearray.join("\r\n")).gsub("\r\n","<br />")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason it has to be a `<br />` tag? Could you use a list instead?

```
<ul>
  <% somearray.each do |item| %>
    <%= content_tag :li, item %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it will do for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`raw`  and `h` provide ways to apply this default behavior selectively.

```
<%= raw user_values_array.map {|user_value| h user_value }.join('<br />') %>
```

Better still, Rails 3.1 introduced `safe_join(array, sep)` for this purpose. Used with `html_safe` it can do what you need.

```
<%= safe_join(user_values_array, "<br />".html_safe) %>
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join)

Comment: Also you can use the `tag` helper, like this: `safe_join(somearray.split('\\n'), tag(:br))`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
raw somearray.join("<br />")
```

Comment: Note that this will trust the array elements as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, the state-of-the-art way to solve this is:

```rb
# Inside a view:
safe_join(somearray, '<br />')

# From somewhere else, given the current controller:
controller.helpers.safe_join(somearray, '<br />')
```